# Adding single backslash to binary string in python

Tags: python, binary, pyserial

Am communicating with a piece of equipment over RS232, and it seems to only interpret commands correctly when issued commands in the following format:

b'\xXX'

for example:

equipment_ser.write(b'\xE1')

The argument is variable, and so I convert to hex before formatting the command. I'm having trouble coming up with a consistent way to ensure only 1 backslash while preserving the hex command. I need the entire range - \x00 to \xFF.

One approach was to use 'unicode escape':

```
    setpoint_command_INT = 1

    setpoint_command_HEX = "{0:#0{1}x}".format(setpoint_command_INT,4)
    
    setpoint_command_HEX_partially_formatted = r'\x' + setpoint_command_HEX[2:4]

    setpoint_command_HEX_fully_formatted = setpoint_command_HEX_partially_formatted.encode('utf_8').decode('unicode_escape')
```

works ok for the above example:

```
Out[324]: '\x01'
```

but not for large numbers where the code process changes it:

```
setpoint_command_INT = 240

Out[332]: 'ð'
```

How can I format this command so that I have the single backslash while preserving the ability to command across the full range 0-255?

Thanks

Edit:

The correct way to do this is as said by Michael below:

```
bytes((240,))
```

Thank you for the prompt responses.

Comment: You don't need the backslash **representation** to send the right byte. To create a single byte of e. g. decimal value 240, use `bytes((240,))`.

Comment: Please be careful and make sure you write exactly what you mean. `'b\xXX'` is not the same as `b'\xXX'`. The latter makes sense as a way to describe a `bytes` object containing a single byte; the former is a very strange encoding.

Comment: Typo corrected, thanks

Comment: Okay; now carefully consider the implications for the rest of your code. Where the output is `'\x01'`, that is **not what you want**; it is not even the right *type* of data. It is a `str`, where you want `bytes`.

Comment: ð is the character corresponding to decimal 240 in utf-8

Comment: You *could* fix this by `.encode`ing again, but the *right way* to fix the problem is as @MichaelButscher says.

Comment: Anyway, the point is that you are conceptualizing the problem wrongly. It is important to understand the difference between a *representation of* a thing and the thing itself. You cannot solve the problem by "adding a backslash" to the data, because the data you want *does not contain* a backslash. Just like you cannot turn me into Karla by sticking an `a` on me: I am not my name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are sending a single byte

```
equipment_ser.write(b'\xE1')
```

In other words, you're sending decimal 225 but as a single byte.

For any integer value in the range 0-255 you can create its byte equivalent by:

```
import sys
N = 225 # for example
b = N.to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder)
equipment_ser.write(b)
```